# What is the difference between "jmp function" and "mov function, %eip"

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, instructions, instruction-set

What is the difference between `jmp function` and `mov function, %eip`

Actually, What happens when i change the `eip` value forcefully?

I know that a `eip` is instruction pointer that pointing the instruction that will be executed by CPU.

This means that the CPU reads the `eip` and load the instruction from memory by referring `eip`.

Is it possible?

Comment: `mov $function, %eip` doesn't assemble; that's not how x86 works.  The instruction for moving values to EIP is called `jmp`.

Comment: There is no instruction `mov function,%eip`.  On i386, `%eip` is not a general purpose register.

Comment: What does work though is `mov something,%cs`.  I recall this causing a far jump on 8086, but I'm not sure on what the effect is on later architectures.  Similarly, the 8086 had `pop %cs` causing a far jump, but this instruction was actually removed in the 80186.

Comment: @fuz: I think I recall someone commenting that only *early* 8086 silicon supported `mov` or `pop` to set `CS`.  Both are invalid in 186 and later: see the current docs for `mov`: https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/MOV.  *The MOV instruction cannot be used to load the CS register. Attempting to do so results in an invalid opcode exception (`#UD`). To load the CS register, use the far JMP, CALL, or RET instruction.*